# How to keep the first four strings in a list?

Tags: r, string

I have a list of 49 rows.  Each line in the list contains a series of strings like below:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "ANGEL"   "Jan"     "R"       "26"      "PO"      "Box"     "40426"   "Olympia" "WA"      "98504"  

[[2]]
 [1] "BAILEY"  "Barbara" "R"       "10"      "PO"      "Box"     "40410"   "Olympia" "WA"      "98504"
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to keep the first four strings in every row and to remove everything else.  I'm not experienced with strings and am struggling to do this.  Can anyone make a suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: `lapply(yourlist, head, n = 4)`

Comment: `lapply(mylist, '[', 1:4)`

Comment: Or `lapply(L, magrittr::extract, 1:4)`, if you want it more human readable than `[`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *@Roland* stated in comments you can use `head`

```
L <- replicate(2, month.abb, simplify=F)

lapply(L, head, n=5)
# [[1]]
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May"
```

Or, if the elements have gaps, use the bracket function (also works without gaps though).

```
lapply(L, `[`, c(1, 3, 5))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Jan" "Mar" "May"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Jan" "Mar" "May"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use also use `magrittr::extract`

```
library(purrr)
map(L, magrittr::extract, c(1, 3, 5))
```